# codeigniter - how to create two forms that "share" a input field

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm wondering how to resolve an issue where I have one text box and two buttons. 
Each button needs the same data in the text box to accomplish its task.

One button is to update the existing record they are reviewing (with the new value in the text box), and the other button is used to add a new record (again, using the new value in the text).

One idea I had was to use jquery to update a hidden text box that gets updated when the visible text box is modified by the user.

So something like this: (this is just pseudocode...)

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="controller1/method1">
     <input type=text name=visibleTextBoxForForm1></input>
     <button type=submit value=UPdate>
 </form>
 <form name="form2" method="post" action="controller2/method2">
     <input type=hidden name=hiddenTextBoxforForm2></input>
     <button type=submit value=New>
 </form>
 <script>
        $('#visibleTextBoxForForm1').live('change', function() {
             //update a hidden textbox in form2 with value of this textbox.
         });
 </script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How would your `controller1/method1` determine which form you have submitted? Both would send exactly the same data to the server.

Comment: Standard HTML wouldn't support this (as far as I know). You would need to use JS, in which case there are many ways of doing it, including the method you show. @lanzz: I'm guess that was a typo. He probably meant a diff method.

Comment: if you need to take different actions based on the submit pressed, you can have that submit button value checked on your backend script and react accordingly, having all the inputs in a single form.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant for each form to post to a different controller and method.  i fixed my post - just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do it via JQuery.  Tie a clicklistener for each button and provide the correct URL to the form on click.

Here's some quick code... you'd have to correct the proper jquery queries for the correct elements.

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
   <input type=text name=visibleTextBoxForForm1></input>
   <button type=button value=Update>
   <button type=button value=New>
</form>

<script>
    $('update').click(function() {
          $(form1).attr('action', <update url>).submit();
    });

    $('new').click(function() {
          $(form1).attr('action', <new url>).submit(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Dunno.  I bumped you back up to 0.

Comment: Thanks kevin; but to whoever downvoted, if there's a good reason, I'd like to know.  We're all here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only field, then simply have one form with two buttons and handle that text data based on the name of the button used to submit it.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="controller1/method1">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert New Data" />
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Existing Data" />
</form>
```

PHP (not CodeIgniter, since I'm not familiar with that framework):

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    // insert $_POST['text']
} else if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    // update $_POST['text']
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: I'll leave it here anyway in case it can help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: In that case if user press enter in text field form will be submitted with `insert` value

Comment: ...and?  Again, this was an answer made before the OP edited his question.  It's also not meant to be complete, but to rather get at the heart of his question.